# Как убрать рекламу в в приложении?

Tags: android

Как убрать эту рекламу в прямоугольнике сверху? Очень часто выходит, что мешает очень (Без отключения интернета).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что взлом чужих приложений не входит в тематику этого ресурса.

Comment: Кто-то писал это приложение, я так понимаю оно бесплатное, а реклама - это лишь скромный зароботок. Цените труд других!

Comment: Незаконная модификация программы это уголовное преступление :)

Comment: Правильные говорят Pavloff, Виталий и Металур. Банить нужно за такие вопросы. Реклама это наш заработок хоть какой - то. А если надоела реклама то купите платную версию и все рекламы вас будут обходить стороной.

Answer (score 2):

1. Декомпилировать apk файл
2. Убрать тег баннера из разметки.
3. Пересобрать приложение
4. Установить
5. Запустить.

Всё, рекламы нет.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29674/discussion-on-answer-by-------).

Answer (score 1):

Установить firewall, который будет блокировать доступ к соответствующему сайту.